# Existential and universal Quantifiers in AI

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I have just started first order predicate logic.
Why does universal quantifier and single implication go together?
Similarly existential quantifier and conjunction go together?

Take the statement: *Some frogs are green*
Why then is this an incorrect translation: `∃x (frog(x) → green(x))`?

Also, for the statement: *All frogs are green* `(∀x)(frog(x) → green(x))` does not seem a correct translation; as in the cases where frog(x) becomes false the expression `(∀x)(frog(x) → green(x))` will be always true.

*Explaining with truth table will be helpful*

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that by "go together" you mean the following:

*All frogs are green* means the same as *for all things, if they are a frog, they are green*, or, as a formula of first order predicate logic:

```
(∀x)(frog(x) → green(x))
```

*Some frogs are green* means the same as *some things are both frog and green* i.e.

```
(∃x)(frog(x) ∧ green(x))
```

Then you ask:

> Take the statement: *Some frogs are green*  Why then is this an incorrent translation: `(∃x)(frog(x) →  green(x))`

Now, if some frogs are green, indeed `(∃x)(frog(x) →  green(x))` is true! But the *converse* is not true: As soon as there is one non-frog in your domain, 
`(∃x)(frog(x) →  green(x))` is true, even if there is no green frog to be seen, ie. even if *Some frogs are green* is false.

So `(∃x)(frog(x) →  green(x))` **doesn't mean the same** as *some frogs are green*

(see also [this discussion](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/4119/question-about-some-a-is-b-in-logic) at philosophy.stackexchange.com)

> Also, for the statement: *All frogs are green* `(∀x)(frog(x) → green(x))` does not seem a correct translation; as in the cases where `frog(x)` becomes false  the expression `(∀x)(frog(x) → green(x))` will be always true.

I *think* you want to say here that if there are no frogs  `(∀x)(frog(x) → green(x))` is true, while in your (and Aristotle's)  opinion *All frogs are green* is not, in that case. This is the old and venerable question of the [existential import](http://afteraristotle.net/2014/04/13/universal-propositions-and-existential-import/) of universal propositions. It has a long and fascinating history; suffice to say that modern logicians and philosophers hold that in a world without frogs *All frogs are green* is true (as is *All frogs are red*)

Comment: I did not get you.
Do you mean, the problem with (∃x)(frog(x) → green(x)) is that it becomes true if x is non-frog?
If yes, then the same problem can be with (∀x)(frog(x) → green(x)), for any non-frog it will be true here as well.

Comment: No,  I just say that (∃x)(frog(x) → green(x))  can be true even if "Some frogs are green" is false, so they cannot mean the same.  (∀x)(frog(x) → green(x)) may well be true even if there are non-frogs (just have a look in your local park)

Comment: Similarly, (∀x)(frog(x) → green(x)) can be true if "All frogs are green" is false. Am I not seeing something here?

Comment: If "all frogs are green" is false, there must be some non-green frog. Call this frog "kermit", then frog(kermit) → green(kermit) is false, from which follows that  (∀x)(frog(x) → green(x))  is false

Comment: Thank you sir for the help, though I am still not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

If some frogs are green, then:
∃ x : Frog(x) => Green(x)
Sounds correct to me...